# iOS GameCenter Integration Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

In DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions I am trying to authenticate the player with this code

```
    // Authenticate Player with Game Center

GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

// Handle the call back from Game Center Authentication

[localPlayer localPlayer.authenticateHandler:^(NSError *error)
 {
     if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
     {
         // Player was successfully authenticated.
         // Perform additional tasks for the authenticated player.
     }
     else if (error != nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"error : %@", [error description]);
     }
 }];



return YES;
```

}

But I get the error on this line `[localPlayer localPlayer.authenticateHandler:^(NSError *error)` saying missing a square bracket ']' and is pointing at the full stop '.' 
I can't get this working
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending a message to the local player instance, so this is plain grammatically incorrect.

Please [read](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLocalPlayer/authenticateHandler).

You should be doing something like:

```
[localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:
    ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
        // ...
    }
];
```